# SQL check 3 columns + increment

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My being fairly new to SQL, I was wondering if I could use it to solve one of the complexities in my database automatically.

That is, I'm tracking entries by day.
So, the columns we are concerned with are:

- `YYYY`
- `MM`
- `DD`
- `XXX`

where `YYYY` is year, `MM` is month, `DD` is day and `XXX` is a unique number given to each entry on a given day.  In such a way is uniqueness ensured.
My question is if I can use SQL to automatically increment `XXX` (from `0`) if I enter two records with the same `YYYY`, `MM` and `DD`.
If not, I could do a query and manually check (but this would be easier).

I suppose the other option would be to use the `_id` column (that is `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`) which is guaranteed to be unique for every row.  Would that just be a better solution?

I'm use the Android SQLite implementation (with Java)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really need more details to give a good answer, but it sounds like just using an auto incrementing id as the primary key is a cleaner solution.  In general, storing a string combining the date with a counter appended to the end is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do not complicate easy things. Use autoincrement ID for that.